# 'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, gradle, environment-variables

I've just installed Gradle, I tried putting in the Environment Variable so Windows will know where to look for Gradle.   I believe I've done everything by the book.   But when I type, Gradle -v,  I get the message:

'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

So I made a video where you can experience what I am.   I have no idea what is wrong???

[My video of the problem](https://videos-billcory.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/gradle/bad-something-gradle.mp4)

Answer (score 1):

I also have a same problem and this is what I did to reslove it :

1st : add this home path in User Variable = C:\Users\yourComputer\Downloads\gradle-7.3.3-all\gradle-7.3.3

2nd: in the same path search for path and click on that and add this = C:\Users\yourComputer\Downloads\gradle-7.3.3-all\gradle-7.3.3\bin

And restart every thing, you command line what ever is opened and reopen command line and write this gridle -v. Done

Answer (score -1):

You have append path to the 'Gradle.exe' to the end of the %PATH% variable and restart computer.

If program name without full path is entered in windows shell, it try to look into the %PATH% variable and check all listed paths. If not successfull, than print message you got.